# How to use Simon VTs SlidingMenu?

Tags: android

So, this is my very first question here. I have looked for hours and hours for an answer/solution without someone 'holding my hand' through this, but frankly. Im just not good in Java yet. (I am super new, and self-teaching myself).

Question: How the heck do I create fragments that can be clicked in the slidingmenu (when slid to the left), and then have it open a listview that opens a textview?

ie.
you slide open the menu, click an option, the drawer closes and takes you to a listview of options, and each click on every listview item opens a different textview.

Here is my MainActivity code:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity {

    private static final String STATE_MENUDRAWER = "net.simonvt.menudrawer.samples.WindowSample.menuDrawer";
    private static final String STATE_ACTIVE_VIEW_ID = "net.simonvt.menudrawer.samples.WindowSample.activeViewId";

    private MenuDrawer mMenuDrawer;
    private TextView mContentTextView;

    private int mActiveViewId;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mActiveViewId = savedInstanceState.getInt(STATE_ACTIVE_VIEW_ID);
        }

        mMenuDrawer = MenuDrawer.attach(this, MenuDrawer.MENU_DRAG_WINDOW);
        // mMenuDrawer.setContentView(R.layout.activity_windowsample);
        mMenuDrawer.setMenuView(R.layout.menu_layout);

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.ICE_CREAM_SANDWICH) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getSupportMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle inState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(inState);
        mMenuDrawer.restoreState(inState.getParcelable(STATE_MENUDRAWER));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putParcelable(STATE_MENUDRAWER, mMenuDrawer.saveState());
        outState.putInt(STATE_ACTIVE_VIEW_ID, mActiveViewId);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            mMenuDrawer.toggleMenu();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        final int drawerState = mMenuDrawer.getDrawerState();
        if (drawerState == MenuDrawer.STATE_OPEN
                || drawerState == MenuDrawer.STATE_OPENING) {
            mMenuDrawer.closeMenu();
            return;
        }

        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

here is my activity_main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="29dp"
        android:text="@string/welcome" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="@string/slide"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

here is my menu_layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_refresh_dark"
            android:text="@string/about"
            style="@style/MenuDrawer.Widget.Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_select_all_dark"
            android:text="@string/help"
            style="@style/MenuDrawer.Widget.Title" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/definitions"
            style="@style/MenuDrawer.Widget.Category" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item3"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_refresh_dark"
            android:text="@string/cpu_governors"
            style="@style/MenuDrawer.Widget.Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_select_all_dark"
            android:text="@string/io_schedulers"
            style="@style/MenuDrawer.Widget.Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item5"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_refresh_dark"
            android:text="@string/tcp_algorithms"
            style="@style/MenuDrawer.Widget.Title" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/options"
            style="@style/MenuDrawer.Widget.Category" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item6"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_select_all_dark"
            android:text="@string/settings"
            style="@style/MenuDrawer.Widget.Title" />

                <TextView
            android:id="@+id/item7"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_action_select_all_dark"
            android:text="@string/theme"
            style="@style/MenuDrawer.Widget.Title" />

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

and here are my strings:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <string name="app_name">MBQs CPU Guide</string>
    <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="welcome">Welcome to my CPU Guide! :)</string>
    <string name="slide">Slide left to view your options!</string>
    <string name="about">About</string>
    <string name="help">Help</string>
    <string name="definitions">Definitions</string>
    <string name="cpu_governors">CPU Governors</string>
    <string name="io_schedulers">IO Schedulers</string>
    <string name="tcp_algorithms">TCP Algorithms</string>
    <string name="options">Options</string>
    <string name="settings">Settings</string>
    <string name="theme">Theme</string>

</resources>
```

thanks in advance. :) hopefully I did everything right in regards to asking a question, and I apologize if I didnt.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to the link and download the zip file [here](http://actionbarsherlock.com/)

There are 2 libraries and one project file.

Delete all unwanted code and classes from the project file and use the necessary classes...